# Isotope filter with pagination and search

Tags: jquery-isotope

Below is my codepen code the search is not working with pagination
https://codepen.io/SohRonery/pen/wvvBLyP

```
<div class="searchinput">
        <input type="text" id="quicksearch" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
 $('#quicksearch').keyup(function(){
        var filter = $(this).val();
        currentFilter = filter;
        setPagination();
        goToPage(1);
    });


var $quicksearch = $('#quicksearch').keyup( debounce( function() {
  qsRegex = new RegExp( $quicksearch.val(), 'gi' );
   var filter = $(this).val();
        currentFilter = filter;
        setPagination();
        goToPage(1);
}) );
```